# Create a redirect for IIS7

Tags: iis-7, ssl

When i created my (server08/IIS7) server's SSL certificate I mistakenly defined the common name to be 'myDomain.com' instead of 'www.myDomain.com', meaning that https://www.myDomain.com comes up untrusted.

I understand that I can create a server redirect to correct the problem but I don't see where/how to do that from IIS's server manager.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Redirection is not installed by default in IIS7. You need to add the Web Server role "HTTP Redirection" (in Server Manager.)

After that is complete, go into IIS manager and when you are in Features view for the site, you should see the "HTTP Redirect" module.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these suggestions: http://www.webpronews.com/topnews/2005/09/28/how-to-set-up-a-redirect-on-iis-nonwww-domain-name-to-www-domain-name